# L2 normalization in Caffe using already existing layers

Tags: computer-vision, normalization, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to perform L2 normalization in Caffe for a layer. The idea is sort of to use these L2 normalized fc7 features in contrastive loss like http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kb/publications/SIG15ProductNet.pdf .

I could find some links where people posted there code for L2 normalization layer. However I was wondering if it's possible to do using Local Response Normalization layer of Caffe or possibly any other.

I have a final fc vector of 1x2048 (2048 channels of size 1x1). Can someone please guide me about this?

Comment: L2 normalization can already be done in Caffe, e.g. see https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1224 ; not clear on what you mean about LRN, but I don't see a reason why it can't be also implemented using Caffe.

Comment: @bjou Actually it's not already present with Caffe source. I can use https://github.com/happynear/caffe-windows/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/normalize_layer.cpp and re build but was not sure about it.

Comment: Indeed there is not a separate layer for it in the current Caffe master, but it can still be done. Again, see this https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1224#issuecomment-147113995 (includes code example). You could even wrap that function as a PythonLayer for even easier use in Caffe if you didn't want to use that fork you referenced.

Comment: True but I am not sure as how to use that python code with training the net. So probably I will go with using the layer and re compiling.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform L2 normalization in Caffe using a combination of simple layers:

```
layer {
  name: "denom"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "loss"
  top: "denom"
  reduction_param {
    operation: SUMSQ
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "power"
  type: "Power"
  bottom: "denom"
  top: "power"
  power_param {
    power: -0.5
    shift: 9.99999996004e-13
  }
}
layer {
  name: "reshape"
  type: "Reshape"
  bottom: "power"
  top: "reshape"
  reshape_param {
    shape {
      dim: 1
    }
    axis: -1
    num_axes: 0
  }
}
layer {
  name: "tile"
  type: "Tile"
  bottom: "reshape"
  top: "tile"
  tile_param {
    axis: 1
    tiles: 300
  }
}
layer {
  name: "elwise"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "loss"
  bottom: "tile"
  top: "elwise"
  eltwise_param {
    operation: PROD
  }
}
```